# Cant use MyActivity.this in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using a fragment and trying to do something as simple as fire off a toast message and having an issue. I'm extending Fragment in my class.

```
public class UsersView extends Fragment {

    View myView;
    String globalUserID;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users, container, false);

        //Global
        globalUserID = UserSettings.getUserID();
        System.out.println("*** USERSETTINGS " + globalUserID);

        if (globalUserID == "empty"){
            Toast.makeText(UsersView.this, "Something went wrong :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // The End
        return myView;
    }

}
```

My trouble comes in the toast line where it doesn't let me use UsersView.this because "no suitable method found for make text" if I can't use fragments this way I need to entirely go back to the drawing board. Any suggestions? Been stuck on this for a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the `Toast.makeText()` method is a `Context`.  A `Fragment` is not an Android `Context` (unlike an `Activity`).

Instead of `UsersView.this`, pass `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity()`  in Fragment

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Fragment has to be a inner class of the Activity (`ActivityName`) for you to be able to use `ActivityName.this`.Since it's not in this case,use `getActivity()` instead.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Something went wrong :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: If your fragment is a non-static inner class of your activity, you can use `[ActivityName].this`, but in OP's question, `UsersView` is a fragment. So you're basically right, but I just wanted to be crystal clear since it could be confusing to someone else.